# Tensorflow mask from one-hot encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have labels that are OHE in the form of `examples = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])` where each example is an `int` in the range `0:ohe_size`.

My output is in the form of a softmax probability distribution with a shape `[batch_size, ohe_size]`

I'm trying to work out how to create a mask that will give me just the probability distribution for each example. e.g.

```
probs = [[0.1, 0.6, 0.3]
         [0.2, 0.1, 0.7]
         [0.9, 0.1, 0.0]]
examples = [2, 2, 0]

some_mask_func(probs, example) # <- Need this function    
> [0.3, 0.7, 0.9]
```

Comment: Could you explain how you got to that output from the input?

Comment: @martianwars I'll clarify in the post that those examples are labels and not inputs

Comment: No I'm asking you, how exactly did you produce `[0.3, 0.7, 0.9]`?

Comment: Not sure why that matters?

Comment: No, I don't quite understand what did you do to `examples` and `probs` to get that

Comment: Oh, right, I misunderstood your questions. `[0.3, 0.7, 0.9]` is what I *want* to happen. So I'm hoping there is `some_mask_function()` that will produce the outputs I want.

Comment: What math operation did you do on `examples` and `probs` to get to that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your example correctly, you need [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#gather_nd)

```
range = tf.range(tf.shape(examples)[0])
indices = tf.pack([range, examples], axis=1)
result = tf.gather_nd(probs, indices)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for